# Changing order of applying maven spring-boot and war plugins

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, war

I am using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to add spring boot to my application and also `>maven-war-plugin` to move the generated `.war` to target (local filesystem) destination.

Unfortunatelly, when I add both of them into `pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>C:/Location</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

What happens is that first the `.war` is generated. Than moved to `C:/Location`. And later the original `.war` in `/target` of my project build is getting updated with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (it can be confirmed both by console output and greater file size of `.war` inside `/target`.

So I end up with correct `.war` in inccorect location and incorrect `.war` (before adding spring boot) in correct location.

Is there a way to make those steps happen in reverse order? To first apply spring boot and later move the result to `C:/Location`?

I've tried by adding:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

to `<plugin>` for spring boot and:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

for war plugin, but it seems to take no effect whatsoever (spring boot is applied after war plugin):

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.1:war (default-war) @ app ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [app] in [G:\app\target\app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [G:\app\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [310 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Location\app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ app ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
```

Comment: what do you mean by "add spring boot to my application" ? Also in spring boot application we don't require 'maven-war-plugin', 'spring-boot-maven-plugin' itself does the work by changing packaging to either jar or war

Comment: @YogendraR 

`spring-boot-maven-plugin` indeed can generate war/jar itself but how to make it generate it (and only it, no other unnecessary build files) to target local file system location?

That's the reason I think I need war plugin which offers `outputDirectory`.

Comment: Is you problem the `target` directory?